# Is there a way to close the window of specific Excel file using AutoHotkey?

Tags: excel, automation, autohotkey

I want to close the window of a Excel file titled 'Status' with an AHK script.
I tried with the following code, but I end up closing the whole Excel application. (All the opened Excel files get closed).

```
IfWinExist ("Status - Excel")
   {
       WinClose
       WinWaitClose
   }
```

I need only the Excel file with the title 'status' should be closed.

Comment: Why do you have to do this in AHK instead of using Excel automation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is one instance of Excel with multiple documents open. `WinClose` is similar to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> when what you need is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>... so let's do just that.

```
f1::
If WinExist( "Status - Excel" )
{
    WinActivate , Status - Excel
    WinWaitActive , Status - Excel
    Send , ^{f4}
}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try calling following function passing your workbook name as function parameter, as following

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On
DetectHiddenText, On
xlFileName:= "Status - Excel"
CloseXlFile(xlFileName)
ExitApp
```

Please be careful that, here you are using Workbook name "Status - Excel" which is unsaved version of filename. if u save the file but not edit anything then the file name might be "Status - Saved", so program might not work. to avoid u can use AHK feature

> "SetTitleMatchMode, 2" ;this allow u use partial name instead of full name and u could set your file name as xlFileName:= "Status"
>   Just Add SetTitleMatchMode, 2 after DetectHiddenText, On

```
CloseXlFile(myfile) {
    WinMinimizeAll
if WinExist(myfile) {
    WinActivate
    try
        obj := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
    catch {
        Sleep, 2000
        obj := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
    }
    book:= obj.ActiveWorkbook
    book.save
    Sleep, 3000
    Book.close(-51)
    Sleep, 2000
}
else {
    return
}}
```